# Azure B2C include application permissions as claims in the Token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, claims

My application uses Azure B2C and signin flows to login. I was able to add a couple of custom user attributes and embed them in the token.
Now I want to implement UI permissions on the app. (say I want to give read permissions to a view but hide edit/delete buttons on that view based on permissions).

Is this possible to implement such claims (e.g. my_view_read: boolean, my_view_write: boolean) on B2C? Do I have to embed them as user attributes to include in the token?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely do this is B2C by using `Custom Claims`. You can refer to this detailed article by *Daniel*: https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Azure-AD-B2C-Series-Custom-Policies-With-Custom-Claims/ on how to create such claims in custom policies.

Once you add these claims in your token, you can read it in your client application and set the views in it based on the permissions set for the user through these claims.

Pls note that you will also have to set the values of these custom attributes using [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)/ SISU page.

Comment: thanks for the response. But what's the difference between the above process and adding User attributes and assigning them to policy/application. It looks like the end result is as same as what I was able to achieve through the user attributes. That approach is convenient because of full UI support.

Comment: Yaa, this is a second way. The imp thing is that u can add them in your token and read it in your app.